# Copy All cells from A + AC in sheet1 to Sheet3 then delete row in Sheet1

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste, delete-row

I´m currently using following code to based on value in Column J copy code to two different sheets.

I am copying values from cell A to AC to sheet3 if the value in J is "ENDED-LOCATION" how can I write that prettier?
I also would like to delete the row in Sheet1 after the copy is done.
What can I do to manage that?

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim Main As Worksheet, Secondary As Worksheet, Third As Worksheet
Dim iCell As Range, FoundRange As Range, FoundRange2 As Range
Dim lRow As Long, NextRow As Long

'   Define worksheets for simplicity
With ThisWorkbook
    Set Main = .Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set Secondary = .Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Set Third = .Worksheets("Sheet3")
End With

'   Calculate last row on Sheet2 (by column "A")
lRow = Secondary.Range("A" & Secondary.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

'   Calculate last row on Sheet3 (by column "A")
NextRow = Third.Range("A" & Secondary.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

'   Check if changes were made in columns "J" (Information)
'   If changes weren't made in column "J" leave this sub
If Intersect(Target, Main.Columns("J")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

'   Loop through each changed cell of column "J"
For Each iCell In Intersect(Target, Main.Columns("J")).Cells
    '   Find location on Sheet2
    'Main.Range("A" & iCell.Row).Value
    Set FoundRange = Secondary.Range("A2:A" & lRow).Find(Main.Range("A" & iCell.Row).Value, , xlValues, xlWhole)
    Set FoundRange2 = Third.Range("A2:A" & NextRow).Find(Main.Range("A" & iCell.Row).Value, , xlValues, xlWhole)
    '   If value of the changed cell is "NEW-LOCATION"..
    If iCell.Value = "NEW-LOCATION" Then
        '   And it didn't find this location on Sheet2..
        If FoundRange Is Nothing Then
            '   Add new location
            Secondary.Range("A" & lRow + 1).Value = Main.Range("A" & iCell.Row).Value
            Secondary.Range("B" & lRow + 1 & ":D" & lRow + 1 & "").Value = Main.Range("C" & iCell.Row & ":E" & iCell.Row & "").Value
            lRow = lRow + 1
        End If
    '   If value of the changed cell is "ENDED-LOCATION".
    ElseIf iCell.Value = "ENDED-LOCATION" Then
            '   Add new location
        '   And it didn't find this location on Sheet3..
        If FoundRange2 Is Nothing Then
            Third.Range("A" & NextRow + 1).Value = Main.Range("A" & iCell.Row).Value
            Third.Range("B" & NextRow + 1).Value = Main.Range("B" & iCell.Row).Value
            Third.Range("C" & NextRow + 1).Value = Main.Range("C" & iCell.Row).Value
            Third.Range("D" & NextRow + 1).Value = Main.Range("D" & iCell.Row).Value
            Third.Range("E" & NextRow + 1).Value = Main.Range("E" & iCell.Row).Value
            Third.Range("F" & NextRow + 1).Value = Main.Range("F" & iCell.Row).Value
            Third.Range("G" & NextRow + 1).Value = Main.Range("G" & iCell.Row).Value
            Third.Range("H" & NextRow + 1).Value = Main.Range("H" & iCell.Row).Value
            Third.Range("I" & NextRow + 1).Value = Main.Range("I" & iCell.Row).Value
            Third.Range("J" & NextRow + 1).Value = Main.Range("J" & iCell.Row).Value
            Third.Range("K" & NextRow + 1).Value = Main.Range("K" & iCell.Row).Value
            Third.Range("L" & NextRow + 1).Value = Main.Range("L" & iCell.Row).Value
            Third.Range("M" & NextRow + 1).Value = Main.Range("M" & iCell.Row).Value
            Third.Range("N" & NextRow + 1).Value = Main.Range("N" & iCell.Row).Value
            Third.Range("O" & NextRow + 1).Value = Main.Range("O" & iCell.Row).Value
            Third.Range("P" & NextRow + 1).Value = Main.Range("P" & iCell.Row).Value
            Third.Range("Q" & NextRow + 1).Value = Main.Range("Q" & iCell.Row).Value
            Third.Range("R" & NextRow + 1).Value = Main.Range("R" & iCell.Row).Value
            Third.Range("S" & NextRow + 1).Value = Main.Range("S" & iCell.Row).Value
            Third.Range("T" & NextRow + 1).Value = Main.Range("T" & iCell.Row).Value
            Third.Range("U" & NextRow + 1).Value = Main.Range("U" & iCell.Row).Value
            Third.Range("V" & NextRow + 1).Value = Main.Range("V" & iCell.Row).Value
            Third.Range("W" & NextRow + 1).Value = Main.Range("W" & iCell.Row).Value
            Third.Range("X" & NextRow + 1).Value = Main.Range("X" & iCell.Row).Value
            Third.Range("Y" & NextRow + 1).Value = Main.Range("Y" & iCell.Row).Value
            Third.Range("Z" & NextRow + 1).Value = Main.Range("Z" & iCell.Row).Value
            Third.Range("AA" & NextRow + 1).Value = Main.Range("AA" & iCell.Row).Value
            Third.Range("AB" & NextRow + 1).Value = Main.Range("AB" & iCell.Row).Value
            Third.Range("AC" & NextRow + 1).Value = Main.Range("AC" & iCell.Row).Value
            NextRow = NextRow + 1
        End If
    '   If value of the changed cell is NOT "NEW-LOCATION"..
    Else
        '   And it found this location in Sheet2..
        If Not FoundRange Is Nothing Then
            '   Delete row with this location
            FoundRange.EntireRow.Delete
            lRow = lRow - 1
        End If
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use an .AutoFilter.

```
Sub CopyExpired()

    With Worksheets("sheet1")
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
        With .Cells(1, "A").CurrentRegion
            .AutoFilter field:=10, Criteria1:="ENDED-LOCATION"
            With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 29).Offset(1, 0)
                If CBool(Application.Subtotal(103, .Cells)) Then
                    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
                        Destination:=Worksheets("sheet3").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).entirerow.delete
                End If
            End With
        End With
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With

End Sub
```